# Upgrading existing Hyperledger Fabric orderer from solo to Kafka based

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've a hyperledger fabric based network setup up and running which is having solo orderer. Now, I need to migrate the orderer from solo to Kafka. Can I do this without affecting the existing network? Seamlessly I want to upgrade. The channel and data should not be lost. Please let me know if it is feasible.

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation says that if orderer type is set then it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to first bring down the network, update the config file then restart the network. There is no way to do this dynamically.

Comment: will this keep the existing data?